# dynamic timeout for postDelayed method in android

Tags: android, timeout, android-handler, postdelayed

I am showing a wallpaper when  the application starts  and after a  timeout  second activity  starts. I am using below code for  this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences pr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String timer = pr.getString("timer", "15");
    long t = (long)Integer.parseInt(timer);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.Menu");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, t);
}
```

When I am giving timeout dynamically  using variable't', it  is directly going to  second activity without any wait.I am getting values  properly  from preference that I have  checked.
Giving hardcoded  timeout value works perfectly fine.
What could be the issue it is not working with dynamic  timeout value?

Comment: Try it with some more value like `5000` instead of `15`

Comment: postDelayed takes delayMillis in milliseconds. 15 milliseconds is a very little duration. Multiply it by 1000 if you want it to become seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much @ρяσѕρєяK for pointing it out, I got it what I  was doing wrong.